# How to tell Chef to take an action if the desired package to install doesn't exist?

Tags: chef-infra, apt, chef-recipe

I'm trying to get Chef to perform the following:

- Check if the desired debian (can be any package really) is available
- If it is, apt-get install the package
- If it's not, build the package using the source

I know you can do:

```rb
remote_file "some remote file" do
  ...
  not_if "apt-cache search 'mypackage'"
end
```

However, I tried:

```rb
ruby_block "Attempting to install #{node[:bact][:application_name]}" do
  block do
    cmd = Chef::ShellOut.new("apt-get install -y --force-yes #{node[:bact][:application_name]}")
    exec_result = cmd.run_command
    if exec_result.exitstatus != 0
      Chef::Log.info 'Go grab some coffee, this might be a while....'
      resources("execute[install-#{node[:bact][:application_name]}-via-pip]").run_action(:run)
    end
  end
  action :create
end
```

Is there an easier and less uglier way to do this?

Basically, what I'd ideally like to do is:

```rb
begin
   package 'some-package-name' do
     action :install
   done
rescue Chef::Exception
   # Do something here
end
```

Comment: And you can't use the `pip` resource (from the pyhton cookbook) in the `rescue` block?

Comment: Exactly. Because the exception is thrown during conversion which is not in the scope where you define the resources. As such, you can catch that exception as in the example code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could install the Debian package using [ignore_failure true](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#attributes). Then you can install the pip package only if the Debian package is not installed at this point. This could look something like this:

```rb
package node[:bact][:application_name] do
  ignore_failure true
end

# Resource available from the opscode python cookbook
python_pip node[:bact][:application_name] do
  # Install the pip package only if the debian package is not installed
  not_if "dpkg-query -W '#{node[:bact][:application_name]}'"
end
```

Comment: Sweet, let me try this!

Comment: This works wonderfully. I changed your original `ignore_error` to `ignore_failure`. Thank you!